# Knockout.js and custom classes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coffeescript

I've got a bunch of JavaScript classes handling the business logic of a game. These classes are not tied to a specific framework, and shall remain so. They represent players, their attributes and possible actions. I'd now like to employ KnockoutJS for a completely new view which is very data-heavy and features multiple instances of this in-game character class. The problem is the interaction between my KnockoutJS-powered view model and the game class, because the latter does not get updated.

This is an excerpt of the game class in CoffeeScript:

```
class AnimaCharacter 
    constructor: (options) ->
        {
            @name,
            @level,
            @characteristics,
            @lifePoints
        } = options

        # ...

        if not @lifePoints
            @lifePoints = this.baseLifePoints()


    baseLifePoints: ->
        20 + @characteristics.constitution * 10
```

As you can see, there are some basic characteristics which influence other values. For example, in this excerpt, the `characteristics.constitution` value influences the result of `baseLifePoints()`. There are others, more complicated calculations behind the scenes, e.g., during battle.

Now, my simple view consists of KnockoutJS templates:

```
<script id="card-template" type="text/html">
  <div class="charactercard">
    <div class="character-name">
      <h1>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span><input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
        <a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil character-action"></span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-copy character-action"></span></a>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <dl>
      <dt>Life Points</dt>
      <dd><span data-bind="text: baseLifePoints"></span></dd>
  </div>
</script>
```

However, I do not know how to set up the view model in a fashion that allows me to update the character class instances, too. I can conjure a simple model like this:

```
class CharacterModel
    constructor: (character) ->
        @character = ko.observable(character)
        @name = ko.observable(character.name)
        @baseLifePoints = ko.observable(character.baseLifePoints())
```

But this does not update the actual `character.name`, or influence the `baseLifePoints()` when I update `character.characteristics.constitution`.

What is the best way to update the character instance WITHOUT completely converting it to a KnockoutJS view? Do I need to subscribe to change events in a custom manner, perhaps? Is there a way to transparently create "references" to selcted properties of the character class instances? (I'm not a JavaScript guy, so I borrowed the term "reference" from C++ here.)

`ko.mapping.fromJS()` is not an option, since it changes the type of the `characteristics.constitution` property to a custom KnockoutJS function, which means I cannot call it the way I do throughout the rest of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to subscribe to the changes on the Knockoutside and update the members manually.  You can do it like this

```
KnockoutViewModel = function() {
   //Knockout members goes here

   ko.computed(function() {
      var subscriber = ko.toJSON(this); //Just for sub

      for(var index in this) {
         if(myOtherModel[index] !== undefined) {
            myOtherModel[index] = ko.unwrap(this[index]);
         }
      }
   }, this);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LMy4r/1/

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. Especially the for(... in ...) loop is nice to easily unwrap what's important!

Comment: You can also use hasOwnProperty for a more safe approach http://jsfiddle.net/LMy4r/2/